# KIVYMD: adding item to a kivymd list from a text file

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

Im trying to get a python function to read items from a .txt file and then add it into a kivymd list. So far i have

```
class ListsScreen(Screen):
with open('lists.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
count = 0
for line in lines:
    count += 1
    listsitem=(f'{line}')
    root.ids.container.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text=listsitem))
```

however, i always get root is not defined. My .KV is in a separate .kv file, and I am using ScreenManager.

Comment: If you shown code is not within a method of a class, then it will be run when the code is started, before your `kv` is loaded and before your `App` starts.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `self.ids.container.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text=listsitem))`